# How to highlight current row and next row if checkbox is true with conditional formatting (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, highlight

Is there a way to apply conditional formatting to an entire Google Sheet so that for every checkbox marked true, it highlights the entire row and the next row?

My sheet has a checkbox in every other row in column A (i.e. A2, A4, etc.), and when it is checked (TRUE), I want to highlight the current row and the next row.

**Example:**

If the A2 checkbox is checked (TRUE), I want $A2 (A2:E2) and $A3 (A3:E3) to highlight the same color. IF A4 is true, I want $A4 (A4:E4) and $A5 (A5:E5) to highlight.

I know I can do this for each range (i.e., range=A2:E3, custom formula =$A$2=TRUE), but that would take forever and I have a LOT of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

There many be many ways of solving this question. The following should be considered as just one option.

You have a check box in cell A2 and every other row of column A. When a checkbox is checked, you want to highlight the cells in that row **and following row** from Column A to Column E. You have a lot of checkboxes and want a fast method of creating the conditional formatting rule.

This answer consists of three steps:
1 = Build a Conditional formatting rule for row #2
2 = Build a Conditional formatting rule for row #3
3 = Apply the Conditional Formatting rules to the rest of the checkboxes in Column A.

---

**Build a Conditional formatting rule for row #2**

- For the Range=A2:E2, create a conditional formatting rule, using a custom formula.
- the custom formula is `=$A2=true`

**Build a Conditional formatting rule for row #3**

- For the Range=A3:E3, create a conditional formatting rule, using a custom formula.
- the custom formula is `=$A2=true`. This is NOT a misprint - this is the same formula as for row 2.

**Apply the Conditional Formatting rules to the rest of the checkboxes in Column A.**

- use the cursor to select/highlight the range "A2:E3"
- From the menu, select Edit > Copy.
- use the cursor to select/highlight the range "A4:E??" - where "??" is the row following the last checkbox
- From the menu, select Edit > Paste special > Paste **conditional formatting** only.

**Comments**:

- The formula is absolute for column A, but not the row number. This ensure that when the check box is ticked, the columns B, C, D and E will be highlighted.
- The formula for row #3 (and subsequent odd rows) tests whether the checkbox in the **preceding row has been checked**. This gives the cells for the "following" row their own criterion and ensures that the cells Columns A through E of that row will be highlighted.
- By using Paste **conditional formatting** only, the rules are applied to all the subsequent checkboxes and following rows without disturbing the content on cells in that range.